# Extracting a CSV file from XML Response

Tags: python, pandas, csv, request, xml-parsing

I have this code that returns an XML response.

```
import requests

url = "https://www-genesis.destatis.de/genesisWS/web/ExportService_2010?method=TabellenExport&kennung=DEB924AL95&passwort=P@ssword123&name=42151-0002&bereich=Alle&format=csv&strukturinformation=false&komprimieren=false&transponieren=true&startjahr=&endjahr=&zeitscheiben=&regionalmerkmal=&regionalschluessel=&sachmerkmal=FAMSTD&sachschluessel=VERH&sachmerkmal2=&sachschluessel2=&sachmerkmal3=&sachschluessel3=&stand=&auftrag=false&sprache=en"

payload = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"\r\nxmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"\r\nxmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"\r\nxmlns:web=\"http://webservice_2010.genesis\">\r\n <soapenv:Header/>\r\n <soapenv:Body>\r\n <web:TabellenExport soapenv:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\">\r\n <kennung xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">DEB924AL95</kennung>\r\n <passwort xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">P@ssword123</passwort>\r\n <namen xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">42151-0002</namen>\r\n <bereich xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">alle</bereich>\r\n <format xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">csv</format>\r\n <strukturinformation xsi:type=\"xsd:boolean\">false</strukturinformation>\r\n <komprimieren xsi:type=\"xsd:boolean\">false</komprimieren>\r\n <transponieren xsi:type=\"xsd:boolean\">false</transponieren>\r\n\r\n <startjahr xsi:type=\"xsd:string\"></startjahr>\r\n <endjahr xsi:type=\"xsd:string\"></endjahr>\r\n <zeitscheiben xsi:type=\"xsd:string\"></zeitscheiben>\r\n <regionalmerkmal xsi:type=\"xsd:string\"></regionalmerkmal>\r\n <regionalschluessel xsi:type=\"xsd:string\"></regionalschluessel>\r\n <sachmerkmal xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">FAMSTD</sachmerkmal>\r\n <sachschluessel xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">VERH</sachschluessel>\r\n <sachmerkmal2 xsi:type=\"xsd:string\"></sachmerkmal2>\r\n <sachschluessel2 xsi:type=\"xsd:string\"></sachschluessel2>\r\n <sachmerkmal3 xsi:type=\"xsd:string\"></sachmerkmal3>\r\n <sachschluessel3 xsi:type=\"xsd:string\"></sachschluessel3>\r\n <stand xsi:type=\"xsd:string\"></stand>\r\n <auftrag xsi:type=\"xsd:boolean\">false</auftrag>\r\n <sprache xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">de</sprache>\r\n </web:TabellenExport>\r\n </soapenv:Body>\r\n</soapenv:Envelope>\r\n\r\n"
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

There is CSV data within the response got. It is within the tag:

```
<tabellenDaten>
```

How to extract this table and make a Pandas DataFrame with it?

Comment: Can you share your work so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the response with BeautifulSoup and then extract the csv data and finally parse it with pandas as a StringIO object

```py
import io
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# Parse response and extract the csv data
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
table = soup.find("tabellendaten")

# Create a text stream, which read_csv expects
f = io.StringIO(table.text)

df = pd.read_csv(f, sep = ";")
```

The CSV seems to be a MultiIndex DataFrame, so you might need to adjust your code using the keyword `index_col` in your `read_csv` method (see [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html))

### EDIT:

The CSV looks pretty wild. This is the best options I found to import the CSV with pandas without preprocessing the CSV.

```py
df = pd.read_csv(f,
    sep = ";",
    engine = "python",
    skipinitialspace = True,
    skipfooter = 3,
    skiprows = range(7),
    header = [0,1,2,3],
    index_col = [0,1],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the library ElementTree from the standard library.
You can read in this xml and then grab the data contained in it.

If it's valid CSV you could hand this over to pandas.